# Filter in collection c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a collection in c#
For ex:

```
Collection<User> List = null;
```

I need to filter it based on sum parameters. so lets say i want to filter out users whos userID is between 1 to 100.

Please advice how i can do this in c#

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, and you don't need the filtering to be *in place*, just use LINQ:

```
var filteredUsers = unfilteredUsers.Where(u => u.UserID < 1 || u.UserID > 100)
                                   .ToList();
```

Note that this is filtering *out* users with IDs between 1 and 100 rather than filtering them *in* as per other answers.

If this doesn't help, please clarify the question. (Out of interest, why are you using `Collection<T>` to start with?)

EDIT: If you *really* need a `Collection<T>` you can create one easily enough:

```
var filteredUsers = new Collection<User>
       (unfilteredUsers.Where(u => u.UserID < 1 || u.UserID > 100)
                       .ToList());
```

You could even add your own `ToCollection` extension method to make this simpler. But `Collection<T>` is usually meant to be the base class for more specific collection types (e.g. `ObservableCollection<T>`) - it's odd to be constructing one directly. If your API is written in terms of `Collection<T>`, you should potentially change it to be written in terms of `IList<T>`, giving you more flexibility.

Comment: Is there anyway i can return a collection instead of List

Comment: @Amit: A `List<T>` *is* a collection - why do you *need* a `Collection<T>`? That's usually used as the base class for collections with more specific requirements.

Comment: I read this somewhere "As a rule of thumb, you should use List<T> only internally (so don't return it from publicly visible methods). Instead, when you use Collection<T> (or a type that inherits from it) as return type from public method, you won't have to make breaking changes to your code, when you want to extend the behavior of the collection. For instance, it is quite normal to extend collections with events to keep the parent updated about changes of the collection."

Comment: @Amit: I wouldn't specify `Collection<T>` as a return type. I'd use `IList<T>`, which allows you to return something like `Collection<T>` *or* an array *or* a `List<T>`. I can't remember the last time I used `Collection<T>` in my code...

Answer (score 1):

assuming the list is not null...

```
List.Where(u=>u.userId >=1 && u.userId <=100)
```

but this is so obvious i'm wondering if I understood the question correctly...

Comment: Is there anyway i can return a collection instead of List

Comment: as Jon Skeet suggested, you can do `new Collection<User>(List.Where(u=>u.userId >=1 && u.userId <=100));`. But you should also suggest his advise to build your code with a IList<T>

Answer (score 0):

Linq has extensions for this, such as

```
var FilteredList = list.where(item => item >= 1 && item < 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> List<users> Users = new myspeciallist()
> list.Addrange(Users.Where(z => userID < 101))
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider implementing a variation of the [specification pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern). Advantages are decoupling from the User classes and easy changes if your business rule requirements change. It isn't hard to do.

A deliberately small example of the specification pattern (with lots of room for improvement such as a compound specification class that excepts enumerable specifications as constructor or single specifications, essentially combining them like Linq-to-XML does! Possibly make them static, read them from another assembly etc etc.)

```
public class User
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string userID {get;set; }
}

public interface ISpecification<T>
{
    boolean IsSatisfiedBy(T obj);
}

public class IdValidUserSpecification : ISpecification<User>
{
    public boolean IsSatisfiedBy(User user)
    {
         return user.userID >= 101 || user.userID < 1;
    }
}

public class NameLongEnoughUserSpecification : ISpecification<User>
{
    public boolean IsSatisfiedBy(User user)
    {
         return user.Name.Length > 10;
    }
}

...     
public void DoSomething()
{
    ISpecification<User> idValid = new IdValidUserSpecification();
    ISpecification<User> nameValid = new NameLongEnoughUserSpecification();
    User user = new User();
    user.name = "Jaapjan";
    user.userID = 101;
    if (nameValid.IsSatisfiedBy(user) && idValid.IsSatisfiedBy(user))
        ...;
}
```

Comment: It would great if you could post an example for future reference.

Comment: An example is added for your pleasure, Preet.

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't it be `nameValid.IsSatisfiedBy(user) && idValid.IsSatisfiedBy(user)` and how would he use this for his collection?

Comment: @preet: Yes, it should be like you said. And he would make a ISpecification to select only those whom he considers valid and collect them in a list. Benefit in this way is that you can externalize the business rules in another assembly or even make them configurable/updateable.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<User> lst = null; //ATTENTION! you need to initialize a REAL collection here
List<User> myList = lst.FindAll(x=>x.userID>0 and x.userID<101);
```

Comment: I would prefer "Where" over "FindAll", as "FindAll" is a function defined in List<T> and returns the selected items immediately. Its like calling Where(condition).ToList().

Answer (score 0):

```
var sds = from s in list where s.ProdId > 1 && s.ProdId < 100 select s
```